# Nginx location block for symlink?

Tags: nginx, symlink

Is it possible to create a location block in Nginx to restrict access to a symlink?

We're using the link to access phpmyadmin, which we'd like to restrict access to. But this doesn't work:

```
location ^~ /symlink {
    allow xx.xx.xxx.xxx; 
    deny all;
}
```

It is not allowing access for the ip.

Or is there a better way to restrict access to the symlink by ip?

Comment: By symlink you mean a filesystem symlink? Why is that relevant?

Comment: It's a symlink pointing to `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.
It's relevant because I'm asking if that will work in a location block.